# USB to SATA adapter disconnecting and connecting and or erroring, only on one machine

Tags: linux, usb-storage, usb-to-sata

I have two identical SATA to USB adapters (from Ugreen) one of which constantly disconnects and connects and or errors. It won't happen every single time but does most of the time.

I don't think it's a problem with the adapter because it works on another machine (both up-to-date Arch Linux).

`dmesg` for connect 2.5" HDD, mount, create folder, unmount, disconnect:

```
[Feb26 12:47] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 63 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.017190] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0.000006] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  +0.000002] usb 3-2: Product: Ugreen Storage Device
[  +0.000001] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Ugreen
[  +0.000002] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 26A1EE832616
[  +0.003683] scsi host2: uas
[  +3.706650] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  MQ01ABF050       0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  +0.001545] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[  +0.000117] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  +0.000004] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  +0.000155] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  +0.000177] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Preferred minimum I/O size 512 bytes
[  +0.000005] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[  +0.038490]  sdb: sdb1
[  +0.000156] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[Feb26 12:49] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#11 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[  +0.000007] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#11 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 0a 08 00 01 f8 00
[  +0.019970] scsi host2: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[  +0.123628] usb 3-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 63 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.018044] scsi host2: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[  +2.295023] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 63
[  +0.000253] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[  +0.000004] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 01 00
[  +0.000025] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  +0.000002] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 01 00
[  +0.000001] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2048 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  +0.000008] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2048 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  +0.000003] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[  +0.000642] device offline error, dev sdb, sector 34816 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  +0.000008] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 32768, lost async page write
[  +0.000007] device offline error, dev sdb, sector 36096 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  +0.000003] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 34048, lost async page write
[  +0.000003] device offline error, dev sdb, sector 36352 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 109 prio class 2
[  +0.000004] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 34304, lost async page write
[  +0.000002] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 34305, lost async page write
[  +0.000002] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 34306, lost async page write
[  +0.000002] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 34307, lost async page write
[  +0.000003] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 34308, lost async page write
[  +0.000002] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 34309, lost async page write
[  +0.000002] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 34310, lost async page write
[  +0.000087] device offline error, dev sdb, sector 36461 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 147 prio class 2
[  +0.000210] device offline error, dev sdb, sector 2048 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  +0.002275] device offline error, dev sdb, sector 36096 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  +0.000828] exFAT-fs (sdb1): error, failed to access to FAT (entry 0x00000007, err:-5)
[  +0.000007] exFAT-fs (sdb1): Filesystem has been set read-only
[  +0.032318] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  +0.219940] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  +0.273437] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 64 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.017198] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0.000007] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  +0.000002] usb 3-2: Product: Ugreen Storage Device
[  +0.000002] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Ugreen
[  +0.000001] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 26A1EE832616
[  +0.001637] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  +0.000174] scsi host2: usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[  +1.197468] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  MQ01ABF050       0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  +0.000408] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[  +0.000278] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  +0.000002] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  +0.000276] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  +0.122178]  sdb: sdb1
[  +0.000132] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Opposed to the working adapter on the same machine and port:

```
[  +3.196595] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 67 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.017231] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0.000005] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  +0.000002] usb 3-2: Product: Ugreen Storage Device
[  +0.000002] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Ugreen
[  +0.000001] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 26A1EE8303F0
[  +0.004752] scsi host2: uas
[  +3.680414] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  MQ01ABF050       0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  +0.001546] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[  +0.000076] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  +0.000003] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  +0.000156] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  +0.000126] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Preferred minimum I/O size 512 bytes
[  +0.000001] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[  +0.048228]  sdb: sdb1
[  +0.000163] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[Feb26 12:51] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  +0.223352] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  +0.026990] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 67
```

`lsusb -t`:

```
/:  Bus 001.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 001: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
        |__ Port 003: Dev 003, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 003: Dev 003, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 006: Dev 004, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 006: Dev 004, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 007: Dev 005, If 0, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=[none], 12M
        |__ Port 007: Dev 005, If 1, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=[none], 12M
        |__ Port 007: Dev 005, If 2, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=[none], 12M
        |__ Port 007: Dev 005, If 3, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=[none], 12M
/:  Bus 002.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/11p, 480M
/:  Bus 003.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
```

Is this a hardware or software problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe the USB port isn't providing enough power and/or has other issues?

Comment: The same physical adapter works on another machine, or another physcal adapter of the same model? You've shown the latter (different serial numbers), which might suggest that the power supply, adapter or disk is at fault. Try changing one thing a a time, first just move the "faulty" unit (including power supply) to the other computer and see if it continues being faulty.

Comment: @ChanganAuto another adaptor of the same model works on the same port, anyway it also happens on all other ports.

Comment: @AyoReis - That suggests a problem with the USB controller. In reality you probably only have one USB hub between all the ports which means a single controller

Comment: @Attie the same physical adaptor. Both logs are from the same machine with the same disk (but also happens with other disks), same port, only changing the adaptor. The adaptor is for 2.5" SATA so the power is delivered by USB.

Comment: @Ramhound not sure, added `lsusb -t`'s output the the question.

Comment: That could be it, I'll test a wider range of computers.

Comment: As @Giacomo1968 suggests, I'd add, an *externally powered* USB hub.

Comment: I'll only have access to one tomorrow, I'll share the results then. Thanks for everybody's suggestions.

Comment: FWIW, I just received a UGreen product in the mail today: [Ugreen USB-C Extension Cable](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B074K318JK). It’s a on foot long cable. Utterly nothing special at all. But get this: When I connect a Bluray/DVD burner and use this “extension cable” between the source cable that connects to the device and my MacBook Air… It works fine! But if I remove the extension cable and just connect directly? The Bluray/DVD burner don’t work because it doesn’t get enough power! Why does a 1 foot cable acting as a go between help? Dunno! This trick doesn’t work for the scanner. Why? Dunno!